# How to perform Grouping equivalent like Informatica?

Tags: postgresql, informatica

I've an Informatica function which I want to convert into query to be getting used in Spring Batch code.

I've a table `EMPLOYEE` table having `15 fields` (all I want in select) and Informatica has function Router which creates group based on S`TATUS_CD = 'A'` and default (means all other records should go here - where status is other than A).

How can we do in Postgres?

I've all the employees and I want to check based using combination of EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID is unique and I want to simply return the count of it.

Query1

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CD AS EMPLOYEE_CD,
         EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
         COUNT (*)  AS CNT
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_EMAIL, EMPLOYEE_PHONE, EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS, (Create Count Field here)
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Query 3 - I need to group (which is my original question) or Create Columns `ACTIVE`, `NON_ACTIVE` columns as a part of query results where EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD = 'A', `ACTIVE` column value should say YES and `EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD` other than `A`, `NON_ACTIVE` should say `Yes`.

How can merge Query1 and Query 2 and Query 3 into single query ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Hey I've updated my question in detailed now, please guide

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Could you please guide ?

Comment: Few doubts -1 - why you need a count? 2 - why is count needed because it will be always 1 because you said emp id is unique. router in infa is a slitter not an aggregator. Based on my understanding, can  you not use a simple CASE-WHEN like this - SELECT CASE WHEN employee_stat_cd='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'NON_ACTIVE' AS status_cd FROM EMP. if you want count of how many employee are active,inactive, then use this - SELECT CASE WHEN employee_stat_cd='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'NON_ACTIVE' AS status_cd, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_stat_cd order by employee_id) as CNT   FROM EMP.

Comment: @KoushikRoy - Actually we want to take a other decisions based on Count values, If duplicates accounts are present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood the question, your code is something like:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_EMAIL, EMPLOYEE_PHONE, EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS,
  COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID) AS counter_from_sql1,
  CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD = 'A' THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS ACTIVE,
  CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD <> 'A' THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS NON_ACTIVE
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_EMAIL, EMPLOYEE_PHONE, EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS,
    COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID) AS counter_from_sql1,
    CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD = 'A' THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS ACTIVE,
    CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_STAT_CD <> 'A' THEN 'YES' ELSE NULL END AS NON_ACTIVE
  FROM EMPLOYEE
) z
WHERE counter_from_sql1 > 1;
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks, I wan to also calculate one more column if value of counter_from_sql1 is null then return 1 else 0. How can we do this in the same condition ?

Comment: i think COUNT(*) can't be NULL ... in current context it is always >= 1